# Angular5 typescript when calling a function within ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material-5

Having trouble with the following Angular5 code:

```
constructor(protected snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
      duration: 2000,
    });
}    

ngOnInit() {        
    const socket = io();
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {  
        this.openSnackBar(data.message,"Undo");
    });
}
```

Depending on when my endpoint invokes the websocket (using socket.io), which all works fine, I would like to use Angular Material snackbar to display my data.message from socket.

Unfortunately, I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.openSnackBar is not a function"
```

Unsure what I am doing wrong here and is the above possible?

Comment: Use a fat arrow function for your callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrow function `=>` instead -

```
socket.on('notification', (data) => {  
    this.openSnackBar(data.message,"Undo");
});
```

Because, it does not have its own `this`

Comment: Worked perfectly